# How to draw inside a view in a UIScrollView or UIViewVontroller?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, glkit

I want to implement a signature feature in my tabbar application. I want to add a `subView` to a `UIScrollView` or `UIViewController` (which ever is the more appropriate and easier). Which control should I use for it?
I want to pick the touch events on the signature view and draw on those points to get the signature. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Help about what? What is the problem? You ask how to add a sub view or, how to implement the signature view, or something else? Did you try something, before asking?

Comment: I tried working with GLKit but to no help. I want to know which control to use for drawing on touch events, and how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just a UIView for drawing points get touched. I needed to implement something like that and the following page was really helpful. It explains all with code. You may want to check it out.

http://www.effectiveui.com/blog/2011/12/02/how-to-build-a-simple-painting-app-for-ios/

Comment: Thank you. That's a great tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

**First thing you need to read is this** - [http://developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)
and check this apple demo - [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html)

after that you may check this - [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/)